# Best Practice for Devices & iOS Versions for Testing. Need Multiple iOS Versions on same device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I'm trying to assess my array of devices and versions for testing with iPhone 5 coming out. we've got:

- iPhone 5 with iOS 6
- iPhone 4S with iOS 5
- iPhone 4 with iOS 5
- iPhone 4 with iOS 4
- iPad 1 with iOS 5

I definitely want to keep something with iOS 4 (although soon that might not be necessary), but i was going to sell the iPhone 4 w/ iOS 5. Is it important to have a iPhone 4 or 4S with iOS 6 or will having iPhone 5 with iOS 6 be sufficient to test for that iOS version?

Comment: It is rather subjective question, but personally I think since iOS6 is the newest OS so will likely cause most of the new bugs + will eventually get the biggest user base, you might want to test it as much as possible as so have as many different devices with iOS6 installed as you can...

Comment: thanks, i know its a bit subjective, just wanted to see what others do. youre right that iOS 6 will probably quickly be adopted and the focus should be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say you also need an iPad with iOS 6. Testing with and without retina displays may be crucially important for some applications. iOS 4 support will be quickly waning, and probably only people who have pre-iPhone 3GS devices will care. If they can't bother to download an iOS release, why would they download your app?

Comment: thanks. latest i saw was 8.5% on 4.x, but that will go down with 6 now out. ive been testing SD and HD using ipad and retina iPhones, but ill consider getting an iPad with 6.